# Difficult problem with passsing big data exec function using php

Tags: javascript, php, python

I'am already have problem with using exec PHP function my idea is using PHP to execute python file to write a file with big text but when PHP execute python file it is just passing only one line and I am already using escapeshellarg php function but it didn't work. My PHP code

```
$user = \logined::name();
$data = escapeshellarg($_POST['data']);
exec( GOBA_PY_CMD."writefile " . $user . "  ". $path . "  ". $data ." ", $output, $return_var);
if ($return_var != 0) {
    print json_encode(['status'=>false,'message'=>'Error while opening file']) ; // todo: handle this more styled
    exit;
} else {
    echo $output[0];
}
```

and my Python file

```
def writeSend(self):
    if os.path.isfile(self.path):
       print(self.data)
       exit()
       os.system("sudo -u "+self.user+" printf "+ self.data +" > "+ self.path)
       data = {'status':True,'message':'success'}
       jsondata = json.dumps(data)
       print(jsondata)
    else:
        data = {'status':False,'message':'Failed','data':None}
        jsondata = json.dumps(data)
        print(jsondata)
```

So how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I don't see how [tag:javascript] is related to this post. You might want to change it to [tag:json] .

Comment: i am using ajax to send data from client to server

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved after using json_encode function .